# How to check if inherited property is the part of class (sub-class)

Tags: c#, reflection, linq-expressions

I am trying to create a generic function that can tell by looking in the `MemberExpression`'s `Member` and finding it in a `Type` to see if that property exists in that class. It works fine with normal properties but with inherited properties it does not find them.

```
class Person {
    public string FirstName {get;set;}
    public string LastName {get;set;}       
}

class Student : Person {
    public string StudentID {get;set;}
}

public static void Main()
{
    bool test1 = IsPropertyPartOfClass<Student, string>(x => x.StudentID);
    Console.WriteLine("Testing StudentID property");
    if (test1)
        Console.WriteLine("\tProperty is part of Class");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("\tProperty is not part of Class");

    bool test2 = IsPropertyPartOfClass<Student, string>(x => x.FirstName);
    Console.WriteLine("Testing FirstName property");
    if (test2)
        Console.WriteLine("\tProperty is part of Class");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("\tProperty is not part of Class");
}

public static bool IsPropertyPartOfClass<T, R>(Expression<Func<T, R>> expPropSel){
    MemberInfo mem_info_from_exp = ((MemberExpression)((LambdaExpression)expPropSel).Body).Member;
    return typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(x=> x == mem_info_from_exp).Any();
}
```

Output:

```
Testing StudentID property
    Property is part of Class
Testing FirstName property
    Property is not part of Class
```

**Update:**

With the help of @NetMage I was able to modify my method. Notice that my method is now also covering the cases where expression could be of different sub-class while `T` parameter could be representing different sub-class.

```
var employeeObj = new Employee(); // here Employee is also inherited from Person class
trickyTest = IsPropertyPartOfClass<Student, string>(x => employeeObj.FirstName);
```

In above example, we want function to return `false`.

```
public static bool IsPropertyPartOfClass<T, R>(Expression<Func<T, R>> expPropSel) {
    MemberInfo mem_info_from_exp = ((MemberExpression)((LambdaExpression)expPropSel).Body).Member;
    Type sourceType = ((MemberExpression)((LambdaExpression)expPropSel).Body).Expression.Type;
    return typeof(T)
                .GetProperties()
                .Where(x=> 
                            sourceType == typeof(T) &&
                            (
                                (x == mem_info_from_exp) || 
                                (
                                    x.Name == mem_info_from_exp.Name &&
                                    x.Module.Equals(mem_info_from_exp.Module) && 
                                    x.MetadataToken == mem_info_from_exp.MetadataToken
                                )
                            )
                )
                .Any();
}
```

Comment: What if there's a virtual property in base class that is overridden in child? It will return true in both.

Comment: LINQPad `Dump` is very useful for testing this.

Comment: @vendettamit, yes you are right, but here we have very simple cases no overriding just plan inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ReflectedType` is different between the `MemberInfo` from the lambda and the `PropertyInfo`s from the type - perhaps you should use `HasSameMetadataDefinitionAs`?

See the discussion [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/5884) for why it was added.

Comment: Nice, I am NOT using .net core for now and trying to make something workable on at-least version 4. So I guess comparing the `MetadataToken` property should work?

Comment: @sallushan The [.Net Core source](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Reflection/MemberInfo.Internal.cs,f837137ea25e482a) implies you should verify they are in the same module as well.

Comment: @sallushan It also checks they are the same (runtime) type.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to modify the method and it's working fine, check out the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably IsPropertyPartOfClass method can check for base properties as well

```
public static bool IsPropertyPartOfClass<T, R>(Expression<Func<T, R>> 
  expPropSel)
{
     MemberInfo memInfoFromExp = ((MemberExpression) expPropSel.Body).Member;
     var memberInfo = typeof(T).BaseType;
     return typeof(T).GetProperties().Any(x => x == memInfoFromExp || 
         memberInfo != null && memberInfo.GetProperties().Any(x => x == 
         memInfoFromExp));
}
```

Comment: It may work for the cases where class is inherited, but this is also possible that we provide a class that is not inherited from other class. Plus we can also provide the property which is part of sub-class rather base class, in that case function should return true as well.

Comment: I have tried for inherited one and the same class, wherein function returned true, will  give a try for subclass as well.

Comment: Your code has problem though, I guess you need to close the `||` (OR) conditions in braces.

Comment: Yup, Rider refactored it this way

Comment: Thanks, your approach is also good, but the problem will come if you have further multiple inheritance levels, in that case we have to iterate recursively with all the `BaseType`s until we reach where `BaseType` equals `Object`. I've updated my question check it out.